# elastic collision problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I got this question as a practice question before a major exam (highschool) including dynamics topic. However, I was so confused that the question specifically says it is an elastic collision but when I use kinetic energy conservation formula to solve for the final velocity, it gives me a different answer from the one I got when using momentum conservation equation. Is this simply because the question was crafted poorly or am I understanding the topic wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

"A red ball of mass 0.2 kg hits a blue ball of mass 0.25 kg, in an elastic collision, and the red ball comes to a stop. The red ball has a velocity of 5 m/s, and the blue ball was at rest. What is the final velocity of the blue ball?"

(For further information about the answers, I got 4 m/s if I use KE equation and 5 m/s if I use conservation of momentum equation)

Answer (score 0):

The question has a misprint. The masses of the two balls should be the same, may be 0.25 kg each. In such a case the velocities will be exchanged on collision, that is, red ball will come to rest and the blue ball will move with the velocity as that of the red. Thus, both the equations will result in the same value.

Comment: Or, alternatively, the misprint could be that the collision is perfectly elastic. In which case only conservation of momentum applies.

Comment: Can be so but I feel that the teacher(or OP) skipped the "5" at the end of 0.2 kg mass.